# chrome inspector not showing remote address IP

Tags: google-chrome-devtools, ip-address, web-inspector

This past week I began noticing that all Chrome Inspector Network Headers started showing the `Remote Address` in a hex or IPv6 format - but the format, as best I can tell, is not actually Hex or IPv6.

```
Remote Address: [2607:7700:0:17:0:1:48a7:dc46]:443
```

What kind of address is this?  Is this a setting that I can turn off (or on) to get the true IPv4 address again - or is there someway to convert it back to IP4 ?

Comment: hmmm, turns out it is IPv6 long form - is there an Inspector setting that can revert these addresses back to IPv4?

Answer (score 0):

That is a valid IPv6 address.  Each group of 4-hex digit is 16bits which means it has a maximum value of 65535 - it's a bit shorter to write down using hex representation than decimal.

Your client must be running dual-stack IPv4/IPv6 which means it will, first look for an IPv6 address (via a DNS query for AAAA aka 'quad-A') record.  If that is unsuccessful it will try to find an IPv4 address (via a DNS query for A-record).

In your case, your OS has received a quad-A record and used IPv6 to communicate with the server using the IPv6 address assigned to your client which you can see by entering the following from command prompt (Windows):

```
ipconfig /all | find "IPv6 Address"
```

You can query the A-record (try https://toolbox.googleapps.com/apps/dig/#A/) of the domain you were accessing over IPv6 to get an IPv4 address,  however it's not strictly correct to refer to it as 'converting' or 'reverting' - IPv4 and 6 are separate stacks which co-exist happily.